# SQL SERVER, Agrupar ,sumar y dividir filas con registros iguales

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

Muy buen día.

Tal vez esto sea algo complejo por lo que detallare lo mejor posible.

Tengo esta consulta, estoy intentado agrupar por mes y que una vez que se agrupen los meses, se sumen las columnas **horas** y **guardias**, he intentado realizarlo con un *group by*, pero no obtengo el resultado deseado. Si existe la posibilidad me favorecería un resultado sin subconsultas

```
SELECT NOM_PROYECTO PROYECTO,MES,SUM(HORAS) HORAS,
       (COUNT(DISTINCT(FECHA)))*2 AS GUARDIAS,(SUM(HORAS))/(COUNT(DISTINCT(FECHA))*2) TOTAL 
       FROM PERFORADO AS PER
       WHERE FLG_ESTADO='A' AND COD_TIEMPO=035 
       GROUP BY NOM_PROYECTO,MES,NOM_MAQUINA
```

Como pueden notar existe un columna llamada **NOM_MAQUINA** esta consulta es esencial para detallar las guardias, ya que sin esta solo obtendria el valor mayor de cada guardia por mes.

*Esto sucede porque estoy realizando un COUNT en fecha*

**SALIDA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**RESULTADO AL QUE INTENTO LLEGAR**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ante todo gracias por su ayuda!

Cualquier duda sera respondida.

Comment: Por favor, envíanos esta tabla en SQL o al menos en modo texto para poder copiar los datos, y será un placer ayudarte. Saludos